# Facebook OAUTH2 and PHP/JSDK

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

I have registered with auth.login in order to do an ajax call back to my server and update login counts. it doesnt work as the php sdk is resolutely refusing to see that the user is properly logged in.

JS code:

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    var channelurl='http://'+window.location.hostname+'/channel.html';
        FB.init({
            appId : window.appid,
            status: true,
            cookie: true,
            xfbml: true,
            channelURL : channelurl, // channel.html file
            oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
        });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {

                   $("#fbconnecttext").html("<a>Logging in...</v>");

                   $.ajax({
                      url: "fbupdatelogincount",
                      type: "GET",
                      cache: false,
                      success: function (html) {
                          window.setTimeout('$("#fbconnecttext").html("")', 10000);
                          var rec = JSON.parse(html);
                          window.numlogins = rec["numlogins"];
                          FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                             if (window.numlogins > 1) {
                                 $("#fbconnecttext").html(window.welcomebacktext.replace("%s", response.first_name));
                                 $("#fbadminimg").attr("src", "common-images/smiley");
                             }
                             else {
                                 alert(window.firstlogintext.replace("%s", response.first_name));
                             }

                             });

                      }
                      });
               });

        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function (response) {
                   $("#fbconnecttext").html(window.fbconnecttext);
                   $("#fb-like").show();
                   FB.XFBML.parse($('#fb-like').is());
               });
        FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function (response) {});
    };

(function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
}
```

The php page

```
require_once("utils.php");
logText("In  fbUpdatelogincount");
if(fbAuthentication()){
    logText("authenticated in  fbUpdatelogincount");
    $r=fbUpdateStats();
    if(isset($_REQUEST["field"]))
        echo $r[$_REQUEST["field"]];
    else
        echo json_encode($r);
}
echo "";
```

And finally the fbAutentication code:

```
function fbAuthentication(){

    global $facebook;
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                     'appId' => getSetting("fb:app_id"),
                     'secret' => getSetting("fb:secret")
                     ));
    if($facebook->getUser()){
        try {
            global $fb_isadmin,$fb_me;
            $fb_me = $facebook->api('/me');
            $fb_isadmin=strstr(getSetting("fb:admins"),$facebook->getUser())!=false;
            fbUpdateStats();
            return true;
        } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
            /* exception handling todo */
        }
        return true;
    }else logText("No Valid user");

    return false;

}
```

The main issue is the ajax call firing up the url fbupdatelogincount but the PHP side saying "nope, no one is logged in". Any ideas? Same setup worked fine prior to 3.1.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere, but it seems that passing the application secret to the auth.login event causes it to fire successfully.</strike>

Try this:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    // callback
}, { secret:'<?php print $facebook->getApiSecret(); ?>' });
```

The original issue has since been fixed by Facebook.

Comment: Few questions: What exactly does this undocumented behavior fix? How are other people using this fix? And doesn't this create a huge security hole? Don't you end up revealing your FB AppId and FB AppSecret publicly?

Comment: There was an option under Facebook Application Settings, under the Advanced tab labeled "Require application secret for auth.login" which is where I got the idea to try this in the first place. At the time, this was the _only_ fix that would cause the auth.login event to fire so that the user's session from Facebook could be loaded properly. At this point, that option seems to have been removed from the App Settings and the original issue has since been fixed by Facebook. Such is the nature of working with APIs that are constantly being changed without much notice to developers.

Comment: Wow. I'm having a hell of a time with OAuth 2.0 and Facebook. The forcing the auth.login to fire would have been a nice fix. The way it works now if the popup appears but you are already logged in, no event fires. well, that I know of.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found another solution : in my ajax call back I added the accesstoken as a GET parameter, decoded it at the php url and then called $facebook->setAccessToken($at). Works fine now. So it IS a bug in the new SDKs working together. What a day... ;) –

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function (response) {
    FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('fb-like'));
    if (response.authResponse) {
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
           // $("#fbconnecttext").html('<a class="fbUserName">'+response.first_name+'</a>');
           });
        $.ajax({
            url: "fbupdatelogincount?accesstoken="+response.authResponse.accessToken,
            type: "GET",
            success: function (html) {
                if (html) {
            var rec = JSON.parse(html);
                    window.numlogins = rec["numlogins"];
                    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
                        if (window.numlogins > 1) {
                            $("#fbconnecttext").html(window.welcomebacktext.replace("%s", response.first_name));
                            $("#fbadminimg").attr("src", "common-images/smiley");
                        }
                        else {
                            alert(window.firstlogintext.replace("%s", response.first_name));
                        }

                    });
                }

            }
        });
    }else{
    //logged out
    }
});
```